# Database Engine Tuning Advisor and sp_execsql

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6, database-tuning-advisor

I'm developing an ASP.NET app using Entity Framework 6 and Sql Server 2012 and want to optimise the indexes.

EF6 wraps the queries in a sp_execsql call which seems to thwart the Database Engine Tuning Advisor.

I'm capturing all my queries with Sql Query Profiler's "Tuning" template with the following events:

- RPC:Completed
- SP:StmtCompleted
- SQL:BatchCompleted

When running the tuning advisor against this, 99% of the queries are skipped due to "no tables referenced in query"

Am i missing the obvious, or do i need to tell EF not to use sp_execsql?

Thanks

Ben